# How to show buttons under keyboard in flutter

Tags: flutter, button, keyboard, flutter-cupertino

[image]When I'm typing textform field, submit button should be shown under keyboard.

Comment: Did you set resizeToAvoidBottomInset to false?

Comment: As far I know this is not possible and it is an unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `textInputAction` parameter in `TextField` or `TextFormField`. I am not sure `textInputAction` works if `keyboardType` is `TextInputType.number`.

Here is a sample code:

```
TextField(
   textInputAction: TextInputAction.send,
   keyboardType: TextInputType.number
 )
```